# Configuring Alternate Access Mapping

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, alternate-access-mapping

My development environment is SharePoint 2010. I want to access my sharepoint sites with some useful names instead of http://my_machine_name/sitepages/home.aspx/ I want it to be like http://sharepoint2010/sitepages/home.aspx.

For this I created a new application and its not on port 80. I have some restrictions for port 80. I will be thankful to you guys if you could help me on next steps to achieve the desired.

Regards
Vivek B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to set different port to your application, first go to IIS -> your site -> bindings -> add binding for new port.

Then:

Go to Central Administration -> Application management -> Configure alternate access mappings -> Add Internal URLs -> here set your alternative name.

Also, remember to configure your DNS service or hosts file, so browser is redirected to your site with another name.

Answer (score 1):

Useful names usually involve using port 80 for your sites. I would suggest you extend your new web application to an IIS site on port 80 using a host header. A nice overview can be found [here](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/fromthefield/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=8). When working with host headers, multiple web sites can use port 80. What are your problems in using this?

Comment: Unfortunately the link provided does not include the IIS configuration for the mapping. It also assumes you have a reverse proxy (ISA Server). Not much help.